# Laravel middleware 403

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, middleware, laravel-blade, http-status-code-403

I was watching laravel tutorial about [Authorization Essentials](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018/episodes/27) (8:15) and tried to do the same as in the video.

I generated auth, created and registered a policy when I added middleware to routes file, but it always shows 403 even I change user role_id. I don't understand why it doesn't work and shows 403, maybe someone can explain to me? Where I made a mistake? Also, dd() don't work in policy when I using middleware in route file.

Laravel 5.8

web.php

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home')->middleware('can:view,order');
```

AuthServiceProvider.php

```
protected $policies = [
     'App\Order' => 'App\Policies\OrderPolicy',
];
```

OrderPolicy.php

```
public function view(User $user, Order $order)
{
    return $user->role_id === 2;
}
```

but policy works in
home.blade.php when I using can in views file. $this->authorize and other ways also work in controller

```
@can('view', $order)
    test
@endcan
```

HomeController.php

```
public function index(Order $order)
{
    //$this->authorize('view', $order);
    $orders = Order::all();

    return view('home', [
        'orders' => $orders,
        'order' => $order,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: try to return `true` from your policy or remove the policy as a whole to see if it is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code didn't work because there was no attribute in home route.
Passing variable to url is the answer
http://localhost/home/1 and everything works as it should